# Style expander header background color in App.xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, styles, expander

I'm trying to create a global style for `Expander` in **WPF**.

This is what I achieved so far:

```
<Style TargetType="Expander">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="Red">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: currently looking like this]

Not very satisfying.

**Question:** How can I change the background color of the entire `Expander` header in App.xaml?

Comment: "The entire Expander header"? Including the arrow nad all the gray space around?

Comment: Yes, the entire header including the arrow and the gray space.